# C#.net or ASP.net error?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Goodmorning/afternoon everyone, I'v been testing out the vin scanner `BarcodeLib` and finally got it working using visual studio 2012.

Before i would hardcode the image into reader like

```
string[] results = BarcodeReader.read(@"C:/scan/image.jpg", BarcodeReader.CODE39);
```

but now since i want to use a `input type` in my asp, it stop showing the results.

My question is,  why does it not ouput anything at all at this point?

my thoughts were that maybe it was the if statement.

here the coding

```
namespace testWebBarcode
{
      protected void bnvinoneclick_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           HttpPostedFile fileImage = Request.Files["FileUpload"];

            if (fileImage != null && fileImage.ContentLength > 0)
             {
               string imageFileName = Path.GetFileName(fileImage.FileName);

                //reads barcode (@"filename", BarcodeReader.TypeBarcode)
                string[] results = BarcodeReader.read(imageFileName, BarcodeReader.CODE39);
                string answer = string.Empty;
                for (int i = 0; i < results.Length; i++)
                     {
                       answer = results[i];
                     }
               string finalVin = "The vin is: " + answer;
               lblvin.Text = finalVin;
             }

        }

}
```

and

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="testWebBarcode._Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
   <script type="text/javascript">
       function readURL() 
          {

           document.getElementById('<%=bnvinoneclick.ClientID%>').click();
          }

   </script>


</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">

    <p>
        <asp:Label ID="lblvin" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
    </p>
    <p>

       <input type="file" accept="image/*" runat="server" id="FileUpload" onchange="readURL();" />



        <asp:Button ID="bnvinoneclick" runat="server" Text="Check vin" 
            onclick="bnvinoneclick_Click" />
            </p>

</asp:Content>
```

Thank you for taking the time to review my problem and if you answered back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might find that `fileImage.FileName` gives you the name of the file on the [client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfile.filename.aspx) so you can't use it in your server (noting your .NET code executes on the server side and not client side). Whereas what you might want is:

1. User uploads file from say C:\MyFiles\uploadme.jpg (this it the path you will likely get when you use the `FileName` property in your code)
2. You save file to your server (e.g. to a `D:\<MyServerDirectory>\UploadedImages` folder or something like that)
3. You work with the file once it's saved to the server

I would suggest saving it (see [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1757/File-Upload-with-ASP-NET) for an example) and then passing the path of where you saved it to (considering that it now the "server" path vs. the client path) to your `Barcode` method

Comment: awe, so i was just missing a few steps then. Thanks for the link

Comment: Not a problem, please mark the question as answered if it resolves your issue (and as a note to anyone else who has the same issue down the line)

Answer (score 0):

In your first "working" example, you're reading an image using a file system path (i.e. reading the file off of the file system)

In the second example, you're passing in the file name from an `HttpPostedFile` object.  You need to read the contents of the input stream here - my guess is the barcode read method is attempting to find a file within the file system and can't..?

Read the contents of the `HttpPostedFile` input stream, then save it to disk and read from there if you can't simply pass a byte array to a read method of your barcode lib

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfile.aspx

Comment: i just don't get any errors. so im not totally sure. I'll look through the site once more see if anything catchs my eye on why.